# How to attach a new entity to a single property and a list at the same time

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When creating a new parent object, I need to attach a child to it in two places. I receive the error:

> Unable to determine valid ordering list and single reference to child

My model looks like:

```
public class Child() 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int ParentId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; } 
     public int FavouriteChildId { get; set; }
     public virtual Child FavouriteChild { get; set; }

     public void AddChild(string name)
     {
         var child = new Child { Name = name };
         Children.Add(child);
         if (Children.Count() == 1)
         {
            FavouriteChild = child;
         }
     }
}
```

I use fluent mapping for the Entity Framework configuration:

```
public class ParentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Parent>
{
     public ParentMap()
     {
         this.HasRequired(t => t.FavouriteChild)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.FavouriteChildId);
     }
} 

public class ChildMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Child>
{
     public ChildMap()
     {
         this.HasRequired(t => t.Parent)
            .WithMany(t => t.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentId );
     }
}
```

When inserting into the database, I use:

```
// Snipped out a standard EF Database context, repositories, generics, etc.
var newParent = new Parent();
newParent.AddChild("Felix");
newParent.AddChild("Naomi");

var parentSet = context.Set<Parent>();
parentSet.Add(newParent);
context.SaveChanges();
```

`SaveChanges()` throws the error given above.

I imagine that there is something wrong with the way I have my mapping setup and that Entity Framework cannot work out which way around to insert the `Child`.

I cannot do this in two steps because I need there to be at least one Favourite Child (thus the `FavouriteChildId` integer is not nullable). I want to also avoid moving the concept of "Favourite" to the Child entity (by adding a boolean property) because the child should never know that it's the favourite. Favouritism is a facet of the parent.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that you need to re-design it.

We seem to be forcing Entity into the [Chicken or the Egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg) dilemma here.

- The `Parent` needs a `Child` to be inserted before
  it because `FavouriteChildId` is required for Parent to be inserted.
- The `Child` needs a `Parent` to be inserted before it because `ParentId` is needed
  for Child to be inserted.

**Which one should be inserted first, the `Parent` or the `Child`?**

Comment: Thank you, now you phrase it like that, it's obvious!